# Layout not maintained in Log4perl

Tags: perl, log4j

I found the below exapmle for appending STDERR to the Log file using [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.48/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm).

[Link to the Example Page](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html)

```
########################################
 package Trapper;
########################################

    use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

    sub TIEHANDLE {
        my $class = shift;
        bless [], $class;
    }

    sub PRINT {
        my $self = shift;
        $Log::Log4perl::caller_depth++;
        DEBUG @_;
        $Log::Log4perl::caller_depth--;
    }
    1;
########################################
    package main;
########################################
    use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
    Log::Log4perl->easy_init(
        {level  => $DEBUG, 
         file   => 'stdout',   # make sure not to use stderr here!
         layout => "%d %M: %m%n",
        });
    tie *STDERR, "Trapper";
```

But I am not able to apply the logger layout to the lines logged by the Trapper module. Means they are just coming in the Log file without any date,module name etc. Is there a way??

Comment: The example works for me: when I add `print STDERR 'foo';` after the `tie` statement, `2017/02/03 08:23:51 main::: foo` is written to stdout. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot the thing you tested is always coming but what for the case when you encounter an error in the code which you have not handled. The full stack trace for  that is to be logged by the Trapper module and needs to be logged from inside it only.

Comment: I get the same results with `warn 'foo';` and `die 'foo';`. Again, you haven't shown enough code to know what the cause is; please create a [mcve].